# what is wrong with my 3n+1 solution?

Tags: c

I get wrong answer from both online judges.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
 long long i=0;
 long long j=0;
 long long p=0;
 long long q=0;
 long long larger;
 long long smaller;
 long long cycle_length=1;
 long long max_cycle_length=1;

 while (scanf("%lld %lld",&p,&q) !=EOF)
 {
  /*check validity of input*/
  if (p <= 0 || p >= 1000000 || q <= 0 || q >= 1000000) continue;
  max_cycle_length=1;
  if (p > q)
  {
   larger = p;
   smaller = q;
  }
  else
  {
   larger = q;
   smaller = p;
  }
  for (i=smaller;i<=larger;i++)
  {
   cycle_length = 1;
   /*printf("i = %lld\r\n",i);*/
   j = i;
   while (j > 1)
   {
   /*printf("j = %lld\r\n",j);*/
    if ((j % 2) == 0)
    {
     j = j / 2;
    }
    else
    {
     j = 3*j + 1;
    }
    cycle_length++;
   }
   if (cycle_length > max_cycle_length)
    max_cycle_length = cycle_length;
   /*printf("cycle_length = %lld\r\n", cycle_length);*/
  }
  printf("%lld %lld %lld \r\n",p,q,max_cycle_length);
 }
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Seems okay to me. What is it supposed to output?

Comment: this question needs some more context - I bet I'm not the only one who hasn't a clue what you are talking about.

Comment: @Daren: FWIW, The 3n+1 Conjecture, or the "Collatz Conjecture", is what he's talking about: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture and it's "reasonably" well known, but not quite so well that it should not be specifically stated, I agree.

Comment: Thanks for everybody, I managed to change the code such that the judge has accepted it. I changed the long long to long unsigned int, but I think that the problem was that I printed every time the small number first regardless of it's position in the input, when I should have printed the numbers in the exact order of the input.

Answer (score 3):

Did you verify your code using the sample input and sample output:

```
Sample Input

1 10
100 200
201 210
900 1000

Sample Output

1 10 20
100 200 125
201 210 89
900 1000 174
```

?

The only minor problems I see are:

```
while (scanf("%lld %lld",&p,&q) !=EOF)
```

should probably be:

```
while (scanf("%lld %lld", &p, &q) == 2)
```

and:

```
printf("%lld %lld %lld \r\n",p,q,max_cycle_length);
```

should probably be:

```
printf("%lld %lld %lld\n", p, q, max_cycle_length);
```

Comment: It is probably the extra space and/or carriage return that is getting a rejection.

Answer (score 2):

Do the online judges accept `C99`?

`long long` (and their `printf` conversion specification) is a `C99` type. It wasn't defined by the `C89` standard.

Answer (score 0):

`stdout` is opened in text mode by the library even before `main` starts. That means that the library is responsible for managing the differences in line breaks between your program and the Operating System.

Drop the `\r` (and extra spaces) from your `printf()` calls

```
printf("%lld %lld %lld\n", p, q, max_cycle_length);
```

Comment: Thanks for everybody, I managed to change the code such that the judge has accepted it. I changed the long long to long unsigned int, but I think that the problem was that I printed every time the small number first regardless of it's position in the input, when I should have printed the numbers in the exact order of the input.